# No se ejecutan archivos jar

Tags: java

he desarrollado una aplicacion java con netbeans en windows 10 de 64 bits y decidi crear el ejecutable para distribuirlo el ejecutable se creocorrectamente en la carpeta dist como sucede en netbeans el problema es que el archivo jar no se ejecuta cuando se le da doble click sin embargo el archivo si se ejecuta desde consola descartando problemas de creacion del jar. 
he intentado volver a instalar tanto el jre como el jdk pero nada funciona tambien he buscado en muchos canales de youtube y probado las soluciones y nada funciona.
necesito poder ejecutar el archivo con doble click para distribuirlo pero wl archivo solo se ejecuta cuando pongo el comando desde consola

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un ejecutable con

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

o con

http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

Este video te puede ayudar. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPKxqc8Zg-0